# группировка по 24 часовым интервалам вместо дат postgresql

Tags: postgresql, анализ-данных

```
select
 eventtime::date event_date,
 round(avg(price),2) avg_price,
 count(distinct user_id) payers,
 count(user_id) payments,
 round(sum(price),2) gross
from
 table
where
 eventtime::date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
group by
 1
```

Подскажите, как в запросе выше заменить конкретные даты, по которым мы группируем, на 24 часовые интервалы от определенного времени до определенного времени? Например, от 2021-01-01 03:00:00 до 2021-01-02 03:00:00.

Подозреваю, что как-то через extract, но возникает сложность, что нет дат для вычетания, нужно просто взять целые интервалы от времени до времени (или интервалы + 24 hours от времени) и по ним группировать, как по датам. Возможно также через date_trunc, но не смог найти подходящего синтаксиса.

Comment: Из eventtime вычитаете смещение, т.е. 3 часа. И уже получившееся значение обрубаете до дней, по этому и группируете. Синтаксис не помню, поэтому это условно так: `date_trunc('day', eventtime - 03:00:00)`.